# How to get drop-down options in more-information tab in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, tabs, attribute-options

I want to get Configurable products dropdown attributes all options show in more-information tab.

See Below image:- below all options show in more-information tab.

[image]

Please Help How to achieve this.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 1):

The Different "tabs" you see in the "Edit Product" page (i.e. on the Magento Admin UIX) are associated with Attribute-Set Groups.

- Login to Magento Admin -> Stores -> Attributes : Attribute Set -> Click on "Add Attribute Set" button -> Provide an appropriate name for the Attribute-Set and choose "Default" for the "Based On" param.
  [image: Create Attribute Set]
- Configure the Attribute-Set per your requirements
  (Refer screenshot below for how to go about this)
  [image: Configure Attribute-Set per requirements]
- Once the Attribute-Set has been setup - click on the "Save" button to commit these changes to the Database.
  (Refer screenshot below for more information)
  [image: Save Attribute-Set to Database]
- Go to the Edit Product screen (Login to Magento Admin -> Catalog -> Inventory : Products -> Search for the Item of interest -> Click on the "Edit" link) and update the "Attribute Set" parameter to use the Newly Created Attribute-Set (RSK TEST) to the Products of Interest
  [image: Assign Attribute-Set to Product]
- You should now see the Attributes Grouped under the desired sub-sections/sub-tabs.
  [image: View and Update Attribute-Set grouped parameters]

Comment: it is show dynamic options with multiple optons?

Comment: IF you've setup your Product-Attribute as a List-Of-Value AND Assigned that attribute the desired List-Of-Values - then yes - ALL those Keys-Values will show up in the drop-down associated with that Product-Attribute.

Comment: I want to configurable products dropdown options in custom product tab. Thanks

Comment: If admin select three colors option. So show three selected colors in product custom tab.

Comment: Are you referring to seeing those on the frontend or the backend ?